# Problem with recording image name in SQL with Sequelize + multer

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to write a user image to a nodejs + sequelize + sqlServer server.
The first part of the function is to record the image to the server the complete one correctly.
But I can't save the filename in the img field of the database.
In postman gives me code 200 but then cool I make a get to the user not to record the filename in the field.

Thanks in advance.

```js
app.put('/upload/:tipo/:idUsuario', upload.single('imagen'), (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.send(req.file);
        const { tipo, idUsuario } = req.params;
        usuariosModel.findOne({ where: { idUsuario: idUsuario } })
            .then(updateimg => {
                updateimg.update({ img: req.file.filename })
                    .then(() => {
                        res.status(200).send({ updateimg });
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        res.status(500).send({ msg: 'Ocurrió un error al actualizar el usuario' });
                    })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**user.js : model**

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class user extends Model {
    }
    user.init({
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, },
        img: { type: DataTypes.STRING, },
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "user",
        defaultScope: {
            attributes: { exclude: ["createdAt", "updatedAt"] }
        }
    });
    return user;
};
```

**router.js**

```
router.put('/upload/:idUsuario', upload.single('imagen'), (req, res) => {
  try {
    
    // res.send(req.file); // must comment this

    const { idUsuario } = req.params;
    db.user.findOne({ where: { id: idUsuario } })
      .then(updateimg => {
        updateimg.update({ img: req.file.filename })
          .then(() => {
            res.status(200).send({ updateimg });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            res.status(500).send({ msg: 'Ocurrió un error al actualizar el usuario' });
          })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize/blob/stack-66495393/api/routes/game.js

I tested this with post man
http://prntscr.com/10dt3jq
http://prntscr.com/10dt4o8